# scala regex : extract from string

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching, match, extract

I am trying to extract few values out of an big string , I have an hard time extracting them , I have tired a couple of regex patterns , but they always give me no match. Anyway they seem to work in the online regex sites available but not in Scala. What I am trying to do is

**Input :**

ESSSTOR\Disk&Ven_VendorName&Prod_MO_Might_MS_5.0&Rev_6.01\08765J54U3K4QVR0&0

**Extract [output]:**

Vendorname

MO_Might_MS_5.0&Rev_6.01

08765J54U3K4QVR0&0

I am trying to extract those three values from the input string , but unable to do so.

Can some one please me see what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

//Input value

```
  val device:String=  "ESSSTOR\\Disk&Ven_VendorName&Prod_MO_Might_MS_5.0&Rev_6.01\\08765J54U3K4QVR0&0"
```

// Regex build for product extraction

```
           val proReg=  """.*[Prod_]([^\\\\]*)""".r
                     // """.*Prod_([^\\\\]*)""".r  -- no match as output
                    // """(?:Prod_)([^\\\\]*)""".r  -- no match as output

      println("Device: "+device)

    // method -1:   
    device match{

      case proReg(prVal) => println(s"$prVal is product val")
      case _ =>  println("no match")   }

    // method-2 : 

   val proReg(g1) = "ESSSTOR\\Disk&Ven_VendorName&Prod_MO_Might_MS_5.0&Rev_6.01\\08765J54U3K4QVR0&0"
   println(s"group1: $g1 ")


   O/P:


  Device:  ESSSTOR\Disk&Ven_VendorName&Prod_MO_Might_MS_5.0&Rev_6.01\08765J54U3K4QVR0&0

   //method-1

   no match

   // method-2

   error
```

// Regex build for dev serial

```
    val serReg = """(?:Prod_\\S*[\\\\])(.*)""".r

    device match {
      case serReg(srVal) => println(s"$srVal is product val")
      case _ => println("no match")
    }


    o/p:

    no match
```

// Regex for vendor

```
    val venReg="""(?:Ven_)([^&]*)""".r

    device match {
      case venReg(vnVal) => println(s"$vnVal is vendor val")
      case _ => println("no match")
    }


    o/p:

    no match
```

Comment: @jwvh : please help me see what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this gets closer to what you want.

```
val pttrn = raw"Ven_([^&]+)&Prod_([^&]+)&Rev_6.01\\(.*)".r.unanchored

device match {
  case pttrn(ven, prod, rev) => 
      s"vendor: $ven\nproduct: $prod\nrevNum: $rev"
  case _ => "does not match pattern"
}
```

**explanation**

`Ven_([^&]+)` --> Look for something that begins with `Ven_`. Capture everything that isn't an ampersand `&`.

`&Prod_([^&]+)` --> That should be followed by the `Prod_` string. Capture everything that isn't an ampersand `&`.

`&Rev_6.01\\(.*)` --> That should be followed by the `Rev_` string that ends with a single backslash `\`. Capture everything that follows.

Comment: it throws an Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError:  and there is no explanation to it.

Comment: @codehunter; It passes my tests. Check that the `device` string contains a single backslash `\ ` separating `Rev_6.01` from the target string.

Comment: It worked !! :)  What ever you wrote is simple , I dont why I got myself into using non capturing groups and nothing worked. I did upvote and marked the answer as correct , as I have less points it is not shown in public.

Comment: We sure need better tooling for regexes besides SO and jwh and besides those worksheet sites.